# Animation for Tab layout?

Tags: android, animation, android-tabhost

I have prepared one application,my app contains one tab layout.Tab layout contain 6 tab.I want assign animation to each tab.For this i have used this line of code,

```
 overridePendingTransition(R.anim.in, R.anim.out);
```

my tab layout code is,

```
TabSpec tabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec(""+count);

             View tabIndicator  = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.custom_tabs, getTabWidget(), false);
             TextView title = (TextView) tabIndicator.findViewById(R.id.tv_Count);
             title.setText(""+count);


             tabSpec.setIndicator(tabIndicator);
             Intent intent = new Intent(this, Utils.formsOfAPlan.get(count));
             intent.putExtra("FORM_ID", count);
             tabSpec.setContent(intent);

             Utils.tabColors.put(count, Constants.NOT_SUBMITTED);

             tabHost.addTab(tabSpec);
```

please guide me to over come this.